# Upload Image issue in Magento wysiwyg editor

Tags: wysiwyg, magento-1.9

I got problem with upload image in Magento in wysiwyg editor. 
error showing **The directory is not writable by server**. I've checked all rest setting but somehow everything is showing perfect.  can any one solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all before work on magento please run magento-check php file. This file will check all required permission in your magneto setup and applied required permission also.

After that please try to upload image in "wysiwyg" editor. If you are still having this issue. Please check that "wysiwyg" folder is created or not. If it is not created, please create it and try to apply 777 permission.

Answer (score 1):

To getrid off the error message you are getting   "The directory is not writable by server".

Please firist check  "wysiwyg" Folder exist In the Media folder on  root folder of your  project
If it is not there please create it.
If it is already there please check the permission on folder, it should be 755 or if server settings  not allowing give it 777 and try 
Hope it  will  fix this.

Comment: Thanks Pranav, it works. checked all permission which was given but I could not found "wysiwyg" so I created and it really work perfect. Thanks  for your suggestion. Great,